# gcc 4.7.4 Linking issue: Undefined Symbols for Architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, compiler-errors

I am new here, so I hope you can help me guys. I'm working in a C++ project, trying to compile it with terminal (Mac Os), but I always get an error when I include the .hpp of my class, but not when I include the .cpp

> I tried to make the simplest example in the main to see more clearly the issue.

These are my files:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Point.hpp"

int main(){
  Point p1;
}
```

**Point.hpp**

```
#ifndef Point_hpp
#define Point_hpp

#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

class Point{
private:
  double dX;
  double dY;

public:
  Point();
  Point(double dX, double dY);

  void setX(double dX);
  double getX();
  void setY(double dY);
  double getY();

  double getDistance(Point p);

  void move(double dDespX, double dDespY);

  void display();
};

#endif
```

**Point.cpp**

```
#include "Point.hpp"

Point::Point(){
  dX = 0;
  dY = 0;
}

Point::Point(double dX, double dY){
  this -> dX = dX;
  this -> dY = dY;
}

void Point::setX(double dX){
  this -> dX = dX;
}

double Point::getX(){
  return dX;
}

void Point::setY(double dY){
  this -> dY = dY;
}

double Point::getY(){
  return dY;
}

double Point::getDistance(Point p){
  double dDist;
  dDist = sqrt(pow(p.dX - dX, 2) + pow(p.dY - dY, 2));
  return dDist;
}

void Point::move(double dDespX, double dDespY){
  dX += dDespX;
  dY += dDespY;
}

void Point::display(){
  std::cout << "Point = (" << dX << "," << dY <<")" << std::endl;
}
```

When I try to compile (using 'make main') I am getting this from terminal:

```
$ make main
c++     main.cpp   -o main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Point::Point()", referenced from:
      _main in ccVzh5gg.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Comment: Add Point.cpp in your make file and that should resolve your compilation issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `Point.cpp` to the list of files you compile and link in the makefile.  So change the compile line to

```
c++     main.cpp  Point.cpp  -o main
```

Because you don't link the definitions from the `Point.cpp` file to the executable you don't have access to the functions provided in `Point.cpp` you only know their declarations (parameters and return values) at compile time.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It really worked, I was trying to solve this 4 hours ago. But I have one more question. What happen if have more than one class?
How can I set the that by default so I would not have to type

 '  c++    main.cpp   class1.cpp   class2.cpp  class3.cpp  -o  main  '
every time I want to compile the code?

Comment: You are going to have to take a look at a makefile tutorial for more information on how to automate building https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/makefile.html

Comment: Thank you again! :D